# User Error: Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back

Tags: magento-1.7, mysql

I have executed below query in my magento database.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `catalog_product_super_attribute_image` (
  `value_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Value ID',
  `product_super_attribute_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Product Super Attribute ID',
  `value_index` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Value Index',
  `is_percent` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Is Percent',
  `image_value` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Image Value',
  `website_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Website ID',
  PRIMARY KEY (`value_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_CAT_PRD_SPR_ATTR_IMAGE_PRD_SPR_ATTR_ID_VAL_IDX_WS_ID` (`product_super_attribute_id`,`value_index`,`website_id`),
  KEY `IDX_CAT_PRD_SPR_ATTR_IMAGE_PRD_SPR_ATTR_ID` (`product_super_attribute_id`),
  KEY `IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_SUPER_ATTRIBUTE_IMAGE_WEBSITE_ID` (`website_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Catalog Product Super Attribute Image Table' AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `catalog_product_super_attribute_pricing`
--
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_super_attribute_image`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_SPR_ATTR_IMAGE_WS_ID_CORE_WS_WS_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`website_id`) REFERENCES `core_website` (`website_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_CDE8813117106CFAA3AD209358F66332` FOREIGN KEY (`product_super_attribute_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_super_attribute` (`product_super_attribute_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

It created the table but prompted the error with constraint creation.
Now when I am trying to run my project it displays me error like below.
[image]
I have checked the log file which displayed the error

```
2014-02-14T07:42:12+00:00 ERR (3): User Error: Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back  in D:\wamp\www\rackworld\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php on line 3645
```

Please help me out to solve the issue, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

You have the problem, that the transaction somewhere started is neither commited nor rolledback, this means, somewhere an error is thrown which stops the code to process the rollback() or commit() a few lines later.

The code you provide does not help to find the problem.

Ideas to find it:

1. activate the query_log from mysql, reload the page and check what the last query is, which is fired, then debug from there what happens
2. check the `exception.log` and activate the debug mode if it is not yet activated and check for errors
3. Where is the `print_r` located which produces the output? maybe this helps?
4. Hook with your debugger of choice (I'm sure you have one, if not CHANGE IT!) into `\Mage::run` and all the `catch` statements, maybe your exception is catched there.

Whatever happens, you have to find this place and check what get's wrong. Such errors are hard to debug.

Comment: My magento is not working so first option is out of scope. my exception.log file does not contain any details about the error. I have checked but was not able to find print_r in any of file.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm talking about query log of mysql. And this Array ( ... [key] => syntax should be print_r. So I expect, you somewhere added debug output